# OpenMP - for-loop with recursive call - c

Tags: c, recursion, openmp

I implemented a search algorithm into my connect four game, which I now try to parallelize using OpenMP and reducing the board to 4x4.

Performing the programm single core it need 45s.
Every parallel performance is from 48s-70s, so I guess im doing something wrong.

i start the parallel block in my main "get_ai_turn" function:

```
#pragma parallel private (f, g, c, i)
{
algorithm(f, g);
}
```

The "algorithm" function looks like this

```
for(i=0;i<COLS;i++) {
        make_turn(i);
        if(no winner and board not full) {
            algorithm(f, g);
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(there is a winner) {
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(no winner and board full)
            undo_turn(g);
        }
}
```

I reduced the function to the most important parts to make it easier to read.
My current try looks like this:

```
#pragma omp single
#pragma omp task
for(i=0;i<COLS;i++) {
        make_turn(i);
        if(no winner and board not full) {
            algorithm(f, g);
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(there is a winner) {
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(no winner and board full)
            undo_turn(g);
        }
}
```

I guess the best way would be to only use 4 threads, which devide the first loop - how is the best way to implement this? I am not sure if I am on the right way for this.

EDIT:

```
for(i=0;i<COLS;i++) {
 #pragma omp task final
        make_turn(i);
        if(no winner and board not full) {
            algorithm(f, g);
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(there is a winner) {
            undo_turn(g);
        }
        else if(no winner and board full)
            undo_turn(g);
        }
}
```

So i did this as mentioned but my program keeps getting slower :s
tried it with final(4) and final(8), while the number was equal to the number of threads used..

I added `#pragma omp task wait`at the end of the parallel block aswell.

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is assuming that parallelizing the code will necessarily speed it up.

Comment: More generally, parallelism and recursion frequently play poorly together.  In your particular case, it appears that you'll end up generating large numbers of OMP tasks, each of which does very little work.  This emphasizes task-management overhead.  I agree with your assessment that parallelizing only the top-level loop would be an improvement.  It seems to me that the easiest way to do that would be to unroll one level of recursion, so that the parallel part is not called recursively.

Comment: Using `omp task` on top of the loop will create a single task for the whole loop and then synchronize (wait for the task) at the end of the `parallel` block. You might look at a n-queens parallelization with tasks, because both of these problems can be solved using backtracking: you create multiple tasks at each recursion level, and include a `final` clause to limit the number of tasks you create (allows you to tune the overhead vs parallelism benefit that @JohnBollinger mentions).

Comment: Somehow can't get this to work. Somehow i though this would be easier since the code is not that complex. Or am I understanding you wrong?